# No se visualiza la imagen guardada desde Ckeditor 4 en laravel 9

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-9

Estoy utilizando la libreria [Ckeditor4](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/index.html) en laravel con el plugin [easyimage](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/easyimage.html) para subir la imagen mas fácil, no el que trae por defecto ckeditor.

El problema que tengo es que a la hora de visualizar la imagen que he guardo en el campo de ckeditor no la muestra

**Ejemplo**: guardo un registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. En el servidor si guarda la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En el campo de la BD donde guardo los datos de ckeditor en la imagen guarda la ruta de la imagen errada y con una palabra "blob" al principio de la ruta, la verdad no se su significado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Al visualizar lo guardado desde la interfaz y abro consola me muestra estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mis rutas:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Evento\AnalisisController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CKEditorController;

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Admin|Lider|Coordinador']], function () {

            Route::prefix('analisis')->group(function () {

                Route::get('/form-analisis{evento}', [AnalisisController::class, 'formGestionar'])->name('eventos.form-gestionar');
                Route::get('/form-grabar{evento}', [AnalisisController::class, 'formGrabar'])->name('eventos.form-grabar');
                Route::post('/gestionar', [AnalisisController::class, 'gestionar'])->name('eventos.gestionar');
                Route::post('/grabar', [AnalisisController::class, 'grabar'])->name('analisis.grabar');
                Route::post('ckeditor/upload', [CKEditorController::class,'upload'])->name('ckeditor.image-upload');
                Route::get('/ver/{analisis}', [AnalisisController::class, 'verAnalisis'])->name('analisis.show');
              
            });
        });
```

**Este es el formulario donde capturo los datos con el ckeditor:**

```
<form action="{{ route('eventos.gestionar') }}" method="POST" autocomplete=off enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   {{-- probando con ckeditor --}}
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Descripción en orden cronológico de lo sucedido <span
               style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion_londres"></textarea>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card-footer text-center">
      <div class="col-12" id="">
         <input type="hidden" name="evento_id" value="{{ $evento->id }}">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-4" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
         <a class="btn btn-danger col-xs-4" href="{{ route('eventos.gestion.index') }}">Cancelar</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<script type = "text/javascript" >

    CKEDITOR.replace('descripcion_londres', {
        removePlugins: 'image',
        extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('ckeditor.image-upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form',
        image_previewText: ' '

    }); 
</script>
```

**Controlador donde guardo los datos:**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ProtocoloLondres;


public function gestionar(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->descripcion_londres != null) {
        
        $protocolo_londres              = new ProtocoloLondres();
        $protocolo_londres->descripcion = $request->descripcion_londres;
        $protocolo_londres->save();
        
    }
}
```

**Controlador donde guardo la imagen que recibo en ckeditor**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CKEditorController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {

            //get filename with extension
            $filenamewithextension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();

            //get filename without extension
            $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //get file extension
            $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //filename to store
            $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            //Upload File
            $request->file('upload')->move('public/img/eventos', $filenametostore);

            $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('protocolo_londres');
            $url = asset('public/img/eventos/'.$filenametostore);
            $message = 'File uploaded successfully';
            $result = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url', '$message')</script>";

            // Render HTML output
            @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo $result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Código para ver el registro guardado desde la interfaz:**

```
 {{-- probando con ckeditor --}}
                            <div class="form-group col-12">
                                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripción en orden cronológico de lo
                                    sucedido</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="descripcion_londres" id="descripcion_londres" rows="3"> {!! $analisis->descripcion_londres !!}</textarea>
                            </div>
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor4/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    // var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
    CKEDITOR.replace('descripcion_londres', {
      removePlugins: 'image',
        extraPlugins: 'easyimage',
      filebrowserUploadUrl: "{{route('ckeditor.image-upload', ['_token' => csrf_token() ])}}",
        filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });

</script>
```

He investigado y no encuentro la solución.

Comment: Te recomiendo que uses summernote https://summernote.org/

Comment: @JohnnieJw Hola colega, me podrías contestar si con summernote se puede actualizar la info tanto el texto como las imágenes? también se puede mostrar en pdf y word?

Comment: aqui tienes como mostrarlo [enlace](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-9-summernote-editor-with-image-uploadexample.html) Tambien puedes llevar un control de imagenes subidas en una tabla morph images, con el fin de controlar las imagenes subidas desde BD. Referente al editor puedes mostrar el fuente como quieras , revisa la documentacion